# Is there a way to remap Command + H (hide window) for all applications without installing a proprietary tool?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes I accidentally hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> which hides a window (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>) which closes a window. That seems to be imposed by the app, but I'm not totally sure. The OSX Keyboard Preferences doesn't give me the ability to disable this shortcut.

I have a use case <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> so hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd> is a mistake. How can I simply remove that hotkey so I don't lose/hide my window (when I hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>)?

I don't want to use a proprietary tool. I'm ok with using core OSX or an free open source method. (No BetterTouchTool).

This question seems to come up a lot but usually it's a [dead end](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2287015).

Comment: Instead of asking if there is a tool to accomplish your goal, please ask *how* to accomplish it.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I said in the question "How can I simply remove that hotkey so I don't lose my window?" I'm ok with not using a tool at all, if you have a suggestion..

Comment: The parts of your question that ask for a tool (e.g., *"Is there an open source tool...?*") make your post [off-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). You need to remove such bits and let your question simply ask how to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator but there are other answers that tell me how I can do this that I reject because they involve installing proprietary tools. Do you want me to explicitly exclude them rather than specify what I want?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator is that better?

Comment: That's fine. It's perfectly acceptable to say something like, "If this requires some tool I cannot use proprietary tools." This doesn't constrain answers to include a tool, but ensures any that do will be useful to you.

Comment: Very good. Thanks for contributing quality content. Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using `skhd`

I was able to get this working by installing [`skhd`](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd), and adding to my `.skhdrc`

```
cmd - h : :
```

Maybe ugly, but it works!

I opened up a ticket to see if we could [get an explicit NOOP](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd/issues/73)